# An algorithm to turn descending order into ascending order, but why correct?

Tags: sorting

Why is this sort algorithm correct? Many thanks!

## Task:

Suppose all elements in an array with length $n = 2^m$ are in descending order: $a_1 > a_2 > ... > a_n$, we need to turn them into ascending order.

## Algorithm:

For each step from $1$ to $m$:

1. Swap each adjacent (odd index, even index) pair into ascending order, so that:
   $a_1 \le a_2, a_3 \le a_4, ... , a_{n-1} \le a_n$
2. Move all elements with odd index to the front of those
   with even index, so $a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, ..., a_{n - 1}, a_n$ turns to : $a_1, a_3, ..., a_{n - 1}, a_2, a_4, ..., a_n$

## Example:

Sort result after each step with $n = 8$:

[0] 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
[1] 7 5 3 1 8 6 4 2
[2] 5 1 6 2 7 3 8 4
[3] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

## Code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void swap(int *arr, int i, int j)
{
    int temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
}

void magic_sort(int *arr, int *result, int n)
{
    int half = n >> 1;
    int i;

    /* Swap adjacent (odd index, even index) pair into ascending order */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])swap(arr, i, i + 1);
    }

    /* Move all elements with odd index to front half */
    for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        result[(i + 1) / 2] = arr[i];
    }

    /* Move all elements with even index to tail half */
    for (i = 2; i <= n; i += 2)
    {
        result[half + i / 2] = arr[i];
    }

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = result[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m = 3;
    int n = 1 << m;
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
    int *result = (int *)malloc(sizeof(*arr) * (n + 1));
    int step, i;

    printf("[%d] ", 0);

    for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = n + 1 - i;

        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (step = 0; step < m; step++)
    {
        magic_sort(arr, result, n);

        printf("[%d] ", step + 1);

        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    free(arr);
    free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network#Zero-one_principle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting algorithm.

### Conventions

**Array indexes start with 0. Note this convention is different from the convention used in the question.** This convention helps us see what is going on more easily.

All arrays have length $n=2^m$ for some positive integer $m$.

Given any array $b_0, b_1, b_2, b_3,\cdots, b_{n - 2}, b_{n-1}$, the magic shuffle $M$ maps it to the array $b_1, b_3, \cdots, b_{n-1}, b_0, b_2, \cdots, b_{n-2}.$ Please note that I avoid using the term "sort" since this algorithm is hardly about sorting.

Let $A_0$ be the array $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}$ (that is, $A_0[i]=a_i$). Define $A_k$ recursively by $A_{k+1}= M(A_k)$.

### Claim: $A_m$ is the reverse of $A_0$, which is $a_{n-1}, a_{n-2}, \cdots, a_0$.

**Proof of the claim.** For an array $B$, we can check by the definition of the magic shuffle, $$M(B)[i] = \begin{cases} B[2i+1] & \text{ if }i\lt 2^{m-1},\\
B[2(i-2^{m-1})]&\text{ if } i\ge 2^{m-1}.\end{cases}$$

For an integer $i=i_{m-1}2^{m-1} + i_{m-2}2^{m-2} + \cdots + i_12 + i_0$, where $i_t\in\{0,1\}$, let $(i_{m-1}i_{m-2}\cdots i_1i_0)_2$ be its representation in base 2. We can easily check that

$$M(B)[(i_{m-1}i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0)_2] = B[(i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}})_2]$$
where $\overline{x}=1-x$ for $x=0,1$. So we have
$$A_1[i] = M(A_0)[i] = A_0[(i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}})_2]$$
$$A_2[i] = M(A_1)[i] = A_1[(i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}})_2] = A_0[(i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}}\overline{i_{m-2}})_2]$$
$$\cdots$$
$$A_{m-1}[i] = M(A_{m-2})[i] = A_{m-2}[(i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}})_2] = A_0[(i_0\overline{i_{m-1}}\overline{i_{m-2}}\cdots\overline{i_2}\overline{i_1})_2]$$
$$A_m[i] = M(A_{m-1})[i] = A_{m-1}[(i_{m-2}i_{m-3}\cdots i_1i_0\overline{i_{m-1}})_2] = A_0[(\overline{i_{m-1}}\overline{i_{m-2}}\cdots\overline{i_2}\overline{i_1}\overline{i_0})_2]$$

Since $i + (\overline{i_{m-1}}\overline{i_{m-2}}\cdots\overline{i_1}\overline{i_0})_2 = (\overline1\overline1\cdots\overline1\overline1)_2 = n-1$, we have proved the claim.

### An exercise

Let $a_0, a_1, \cdots, a_{n-1}$ be an array of length $n=2^m$ for some positive integer $m$. For each step from 1 to m, repeat the following shuffle. For each term in the front half of the array, insert right before it the $n/2$-th term after it. Here is the result array after each shuffle for $n=16$.

```
[0]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
[1]  9  1 10  2 11  3 12  4 13  5 14  6 15  7 16  8  
[2] 13  9  5  1 14 10  6  2 15 11  7  3 16 12  8  4  
[3] 15 13 11  9  7  5  3  1 16 14 12 10  8  6  4  2  
[4] 16 15 14 13 12 11 10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

Show that we will obtain the initial array reversed in the end of $m$ shuffles.

If you consider the array as a deck of cards, then this shuffle is [the (perfect) in (riffle) shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_shuffle). In particular, if you repeat 10 in shuffles on a deck of 32 cards, you will end up with the deck of cards in its original order.

Answer (score 1):

### Notations

**Array indexes start with 1 as in the question.**

Fix some positive integer $m$ such that $n=2^m$.

Given any array $b_1, b_2,b_3,b_4\cdots, b_{n - 1}, b_n$, the magic shuffle $M$ rearrangement it to the array $b_2, b_4, \cdots, b_{n}, b_1, b_3, \cdots, b_{n-1}.$

Let $A_0$ be the initial array $a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_{n}$ (that is, $A_0[i]=a_i$). Define $A_k$ recursively by $A_{k+1}= M(A_k)$.

Let "%" be the modulus operator with positive divisor as defined in Python/Java/C/C++/C#.

---

### Lemma: for an array $B$, $M(B)[i] = B[(2i)\%(n+1)]$

Proof: please verify by the definition of the magic shuffle.

### Claim: $A_k[i]=A_0[(2^ki)\%(n+1)]$ for any nonnegative integer $k$.

Proof: the claim is obviously true for $k=0$. If the claim is true for $k$, then 
$$\begin{align}
A_{k+1}[i]&=M(A_k)[i]=A_k[(2i)\%(n+1)]\\
          &=A_0[(2^k(2i)\%(n+1))\%(n+1)]=A_0[(2^{k+1}i)\%(n+1)]
\end{align}$$
Hence by mathematical induction on $k$, the claim is true.

### Corallay: $A_m$ is $a_n, a_{n-1}, \cdots, a_1$, the reverse of $A_0$.

Proof: $A_m[i]=A_0[(2^mi)\%(n+1)]=A_0[((n+1 -1)i)\%(n+1)]=A_0[n+1-i]$.

---

### An exercise

Can you generalize this phenomenon to $n=3^m, 4^m, 5^m,\cdots$?